# Do application settings persist after uninstall on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I suppose I could easily test this, but does anyone happen to know whether my application settings will persist through an uninstall/reinstall on Windows Phone 7? I'm hoping to implement a time-limited trial, but obviously this plan may be a dud if uninstall/reinstall resets it!

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, application settings **do not persist** after uninstall

> If an application is uninstalled, the
>   data root and everything within the
>   store, including the isolated storage
>   folder, will be **deleted**.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769544%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)